# How to find out what .com file do?

Tags: debugging, x86, dos, disassembly

I have old executable com file and I need to find out what it do.
What is the simplest way to decompile or diassemble or debug com file?

Comment: COM files are just straight 16-bit binaries, i.e. the first byte of the file is the first byte of code. Code starts execution at address 0x100 (so when a COM file is loaded, the first instruction is at segment offset 0x0100). Be sure to look out for 8086 segmentation.

Comment: Look like, there is only one option. Go thru instructions and try to find out what programs realy do. Thanks to all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your file using the old [debug command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_%28command%29) on Windows XP or lower. A good manual is provided by Kip Irvine [here](http://kipirvine.com/asm/debug/Debug_Tutorial.pdf). Additionally, you can disassembly it using NASM with [this command](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoca.html), but it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
executable.com /?
```

If it was done by a "real" programmer, it would give you some hints.
Also try `-?`, `-h`, `/h`, `-help`, `/help`
I have even seen things like `--help`

probably you did, but to be complete: did you google the filename?

Answer (score -1):

A .com file is basically a .exe file with a size limit, so unless you have the source code (in which case you likely wouldn't need our help), or how it was compiled, it's impossible to do this in modern Windows. Sorry.

By the way, I'm guessing you don't really understand what .com files do, so try this website called https://fileinfo.com. It has information on most file extensions and types, and it can tell you what programs are able to open it. I think you could find it useful

Comment: Wrong, COM is like raw executable, EXE has headers.